# X509Certificate to byte[] in Java and back to X509Certificate in C#

Tags: java, c#, x509certificate

I have a Java Web Service which receives X509Certificate from other service.On Java Web Service X509Certificate is serialized to byte array using this code snipppet

```
 for (X509Certificate certificate : certs) {
                try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                    try (ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
                        out.writeObject(certificate);
                        wrapper = new CustomMapCertificateWrapper();
                        wrapper.setCustomValue(bos.toByteArray());
                        response.getCustomMapCertificateWrapper().add(wrapper);
                    }
                }
```

CustomMapCertificateWrapper here is the class with byte[] value named field, which stores x509certificate as byte array. My .NET service receives this object CustomMapCertificateWrapper and I try to generate X509Certificate on C# side using this code snippet

```
//Do array reverse because of BigEndian difference between Java and c# languages 
Array.Reverse(customMapCertificateWrapper.value);

                        var certificate = new X509Certificate(customMapCertificateWrapper.value);
```

This code throws me expcetion like below

```
 System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the requested object.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertBlobType(Byte[] rawData)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData)
```

Comment: Did you try to disable endianess (do not reverse bytes)?

Comment: @Crypt32 I have tried it , doesn't work (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) generates output designed to be read in by Java's [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html). It does not produce a standard, language-independent result.

For portability you should serialize the Java [`X509Certificate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) using the [`Certificate.getEncoded()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#getEncoded--) method. The output can then be used on the C# side as the `byte[]` argument to the [`X509Certificate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`X509Certificate2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. Using getEncoded() gives the needed byte[] which can be used in c# X509Certificate(byte[]). Thanks a lot!